# Wpf is only internet explorer compatible?

Tags: wpf, cross-platform, compatibility

By default any WPF browser application will work only in internet explorer?

If the first one is true, is there any addin for firefox for displaying wpf browser applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with a subset of the WPF functionality, [Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/) offers true cross-browser support and can even run on browsers on other operating systems.

Obviously, the Silverlight add-in must be installed in the browser, but the apart from that, the .NET framework is *not* required.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox will run WPF just fine, as long as the user has the .NET Framework 3.0 or above installed.